# not sure how to wire a troffer

Tags: electrical, wiring

The troffer I bought comes with a disconnect, two black, two white. I had no problem wiring in two of them but the third one is difficult. The light bulb that was in there before had its black wire marretted to the source black but the white was marretted to three others coming in to the fixture. I can take the black wire from the source and push it into the disconnect but which of the three white wires do I take from the source to connect to the disconnect? Conversely, can I just snip off the disconnect and marrette both the black and white to the source? Thanks. BTW. Why would there be multiple whites marretted coming in from the source?

Comment: So you are saying you bought a used troffer, and the disconnect has 4 wires, two whites opposite the ballast white, and a white and a black opposite the ballast black?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of this fixture?

Answer (score 1):

You need a disconnect by law, unless the troffer is cord-and-plug connected.  You can twist the wires out of the old disconnect, but then you'll need to go buy another one -- and they sell them in packs of 5 at most home improvement stores for about $5.

### What matters is the wires on the ballast side

I gather the disconnects have some pigtails of wire remaining on them, and you're tying onto those? Okay.

Who really cares what kind of spaghetti they have on the mains side of the disconnect?  Those wires are cut off and not part of *your* circuit.  What matters is the wires on the on the ballast side -- one will be black and one will be white.  And you need to connect to whatever mains-side wires will make *your* hot wire talk to *the ballast's* hot wire, and *your* neutral wire talk to *the ballast's* neutral wire.

This is obvious on an Ideal style disconnect. If you have a Wago style disconnect where it allows 4 line wires, then **you need to look closely at the disconnect to see how the wires relate to each other**.  Typically the disconnect is plainly marked with 1 ballast side wire marked black, and 2 lineside wires marked black.  You just have to look for it; it's there.

If you don't trust it, yank the wires out, throw away the disconnect and go buy some Ideal style - they are less confusing to the novice, though they may require pigtailing.  I prefer pigtails for novices; they are more clear.

Never reuse disconnects. Their "stab connectors" *are only good for one use*, after which the spring is sprung and it won't make good connection again.

Comment: They may be there for load in load out to daisy chain next light, With out  having to break circuit , Find the two that feed light wire nut the rest.

Comment: @RobertMoody I speculated the extra white was either a miswired switch loop for this lamp string, or a regular switch loop for another lamp.

Comment: Ya or to turn on half the light . Or to run on a generator if power goes out. Seen lights where two witches control light two inside come on .Hit other switch outer lamps come on.